# JPA with SQLite - persistence exception

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa

I am trying to use jpa with sqlite. When i attempt to initiate EntityManage I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "CustomerLibraryPU" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
```

I am totally new to jpa, so it would be great if someone could point me in the direction as to what I am doing wrong. I have been searching extensively to try and find my mistake, but with no avail.

below is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="socialEngineeringToolPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>socialengineeringtool.models.Employee</class>
<class>socialengineeringtool.models.Business</class>
<class>socialengineeringtool.models.Department</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:&lt;FILE&gt;"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="businessApp"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="testPass"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://gist.github.com/etissieres/5796622

Comment: I've never configured SQLite, but my guess is that your `persistence.xml` is wrong.

Comment: The message is saying that EclipseLink is not in the CLASSPATH (or alternatively that EclipseLink has seen that you are using SQLite and doesn't support it ?)